Why can I not change my bank account on my online account in my French tax account (fisc)?
I tried to go to https://cfspart.impots.gouv.fr/tremisu/iban.html but I can't see the option to change the account:

How can I change my bank account on my online account for my French tax account (fisc)?

Can we assume you've checked their FAQs (assuming that's what the "Aide : les..." drop-down is) and/or any other help channels they provide?

@TripeHound I'll call them.

@TripeHound done and added in answer.

I've taken the liberty of editing the title to better reflect the underlying problem should anyone else be in the same position.

@TripeHound thanks!

After discussing with two other French taxpayers, there is typically an option to edit the bank account on that page which isn't present in my tax account. The reason why I don't have I cannot change my bank account on my online account in my French tax account is as follows, according to a fisc employee:

You cannot change your bank details online because you have not filed a declaration recently. There are 2 ways to update them:

go to the offices of your local tax office where you're attached to
when doing a new income declaration, download an income declaration, print it and return it by post


